# Mac keeps randomly getting shift key toggled on even with the button not pressed

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

This is really annoying when I'm playing league of legends and i randomly can't use skills or click anywhere because shift is toggled on. By the time i notice it's usually too late. I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas what is causing it. I was thinking it was maybe because certain mac commands are still available during the game (league of legends).

I notice i can use cmd + shift + 3 to screen capture. Cmd + q to exit was available until i remapped Quit League of Legends to CMD + option + .

However, it's not just during the game. I also often get similar problems while typing in browser windows.

Is there a way to disable all mac keyboard shortcuts? or could there be some other reason for my problem? i'm tempted to just buy another keyboard to test if it's the keyboard. both shift and Alt have repeatedly gotten stuck on until i repress the key.

My OS is Yosemite if that helps. anyway I'm willing to try anything.  I checked hotkeys though and nothing maps to qwer + ctrl/alt/cmd/shift.

I really can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: Are you saying that the Shift key is randomly activated? Check if sticky keys is on (Sys Prefs > Accessibility > Keyboard > Sticky Keys)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can disable Mac's default Keyboard Shortcuts by going to `System Preferences`->`Keyboard`->`Shotcuts` and unchecking them. Select the category from left pane like `ScreenShots` etc.

[image]

For shift key check if sticky keys are on (under accessibility):

[image]

Comment: this did not work at all. mine seems to be an extensive hardware issue but I'm not sure. all I know is that it's not consistently pressed down, but often is for long periods of time, or it will randomly jitter on and off to mess me up even further.